# algorithm - Searching for an input for which a function returns a specific value

Tags: algorithm, function

I have the following function:

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(2) = 2
F(2*n) = F(n) + F(n+1) + n , n > 1
F(2*n+1) = F(n-1) + F(n) + 1, n >= 1
```

I am given a number `n < 10^25` and I have to show that exists a value `a` such as `F(a)=n`. Because of how the function is defined, there might exist a `n` such as `F(a)=F(b)=n where a < b` and in this situation I must return `b` and not `a`

What I have so far is:

- We can split this function into two strict monotone series, one for F(2*n) and one for F(2*n+1) and can find the specified value in logarithmic time, so the finding is more or less done.
- I've also found that `F(2*n) >= F(2*n+1) for any n`, so I first search for it in F(2*n) and if I don't find it there, I search in F(2*n+1)
- The problem is calculating the function value. Even with some crazy memoization up to 10^7 and then falling back to recursion, it still couldn't calculate values above 10^12 in a reasonable time.

I think I have the algorithm for actually finding what I need all figured out, but I can't calculate F(n) fast enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "show the highest input value for which it can take it"?  Mathematically, there is no such highest input, since very integer input is valid.  In computer science aspect, if you implement unlimited long digit arithmetic, there is no limitation other than your memory limitation.  Do you mean a natural integer size the C/C++ programming language can take? This depends on your system.  PC can take 64-bit, if you use 64-bit integer.  Or, do you mean in reasonable execution time, the largest number it can take?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, please state what you mean by "Reasonable time"? Be it a year, a month, a day, an hour, or a minute?   Also, are you trying to find the largest input number that YOUR ALGORITHM can take (perhaps you are in a programming competition) in a fixed allowable max time, yet also give the result of F()?  Is finding a general F(x) fast a requirement? Or just find the largest x that it can take, and calculate F(x) for that specific x fast (And don't care the speed of all other input x, or even the ability to calculate F(x) for other x)?  Please clarify.

Comment: Do you mean "I have to show that F can **return** this value"? Meaning that a specific value is in the codomain (target set) of F?

Comment: @RobinHsu Because of how the function is defined, it might exist a c such as `F(a)=F(b)=c with a < b`. If so, I am supposed to return `b` not `a` when I receive c as an input. And by reasonable time I think somewhere under a second. Also take a look at the edit. I changed the problem to be more mathematically defined.

Comment: The way successive values are used in the definition, F(2n+1) = F(2(n-1)) + 1 (from F(7), "odd values" equal "the even value three positions back", plus 1).

Comment: Oh, now I see.  In fact, you requests to compute the inverse function of F(x) (kind of, but when more than one candidate of the inverse function value, the largest one is chosen).

Comment: @RobinHsu Exactly. I avoided calling it the inverse because it doesn't follow the exact mathematical definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use memoisation all the way up to the target value, e.g. in Python:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not self.memo.has_key(args):
            self.memo[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize
def R(n):
    if n<=1: return 1
    if n==2: return 2
    n,rem = divmod(n,2)
    if rem:
        return R(n)+R(n-1)+1
    return R(n)+R(n+1)+n
```

This computes the answer for 10**25 instantly.

The reason this works is because the nature of the recursion means that for a binary number abcdef it will only need to at most use the values:

```
abcdef
abcde-1,abcde,abcde+1
abcd-2,abcd-1,abcd,abcd+1,abcd+2
abc-2,abc-1,abc,abc+1,abc+2
ab-2,ab-1,ab,ab+1,ab+2
a-2,a-1,a,a+1,a+2
```

At each step you can move up or down 1, but you also divide the number by 2 so the most you can move away from the original number is limited.

Therefore the memoised code will only use at most 5*log_2(n) evaluations.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check. For some reason unknown to me yet, I thought that to compute a value it for sure had to pass trough most of the smaller values. I also see that you know the source of the problem.